# Doctrine select elements where contains ALL specified values

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I'm searching for Doctrine function which helps to query related code:

```
select pt.product_id from product_taxon pt
    join product_taxon pt2 on pt.product_id=pt2.product_id and pt2.taxon_id = 101
where pt.taxon_id = 47;
```

it means select all elements which have taxon with id 101 AND taxon with id 47, in other words have taxons 101 and 47 simultaneously.

I tried to use IN(), but it selects elements which can have only one of 47 and 101 taxons ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One canonical way of doing this uses aggregation:

```
SELECT
    pt.product_id
FROM product_taxon pt
INNER JOIN product_taxon pt2
    ON pt.product_id = pt2.product_id
WHERE pt2.taxon_id IN (101, 47)
GROUP BY pt.product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pt2.taxon_id) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tim Biegeleisen, successfully converted it to Doctrine QueryBuilder:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
// fluent methods with conditions which are not related to problem
->setParameter('locale', $locale)
->setParameter('channel', $channel);

$in = $this->createQueryBuilder('k')
    ->select('pt5.id')
    ->leftJoin('k.productTaxons', 'pt4')
    ->innerJoin('k.productTaxons', 'pt3')
    ->leftJoin('pt4.product', 'pt5')
    ->andWhere('pt3.taxon IN (:taxons)')
    ->addGroupBy('pt4.id')
    ->having('COUNT(DISTINCT pt3) = :count')
;

$queryBuilder
    ->andWhere(
        $queryBuilder->expr()->in('o.id', $in->getDQL())
    )
    ->setParameter('count', count($taxonsArr))
    ->setParameter('taxons', $taxonsArr);
```